# python console tab completion not working in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x

running Windows 10

From what I understand python3 has tab completion in the python console already built in but this isn't working for me.

When I hit tab there is no completion:

[image]

Im aware there are modules that can do this, but I'd like to use the native feature if it is available to me on windows.

Comment: did you try hitting the tab twice? Usually, it will give you list of available commands

Comment: no tab inserts an actual tab

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The builtin completion relies on the GNU *`readline`* library.

You may be able to get completion working by installing the python version ([pyreadline](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline)) of this package on Windows.

```bash
python -m pip install pyreadline
```

Edit: For more recent Python releases, see Craig McQueen's comment below. ie. `pyreadline3` instead of `pyreadline`

Comment: Don't understand why this is not part of the site-package for Windows then, license issue?

Comment: Fixes the issue but I can't insert tabs anymore. Not even for running a simple `for` loop

Comment: I came here looking for a solution that works with the cmd module on windows 10. pyreadline works well with the cmd module in powershell (although Rochak is correct about tabs), but it's really clumsy to use in git bash and just buggy in interactive mode (python -i). The package also doesn't seem to have been updated in a long time.

Comment: @DavidW: Answering why the "package also doesn't seem to have been updated in a long time": `pyreadline` was initially developed to support IPython (which used it through the 4.x releases). But as of IPython 5.0, they moved to using `prompt_toolkit` (which is much more full-featured and platform independent), and it's pretty clear that once they made that decision, they stopped updating `pyreadline` (`pyreadline` was last updated in September, 2015, a month after IPython 4.0 released; IPython 5.0 released nine months later).

Comment: I see an error when I try to install `pyreadline` with Python 3.12. See [python.exe on Windows 10 with Python 3.10 errors after this module is installed · Issue #73 · pyreadline/pyreadline](https://github.com/pyreadline/pyreadline/issues/73). Installing `pyreadline3` instead seems to work.

Answer (score 29):

The original `pyreadline` is no longer maintained and doesn't work on newer versions of Python (>=3.10).
Installing [`pyreadline3`](https://pypi.org/project/pyreadline3/) works:

```
python -m pip install pyreadline3
```

Comment: This is the most up to date! Worked!

Comment: adding `pyreadline3; sys_platform == "win32"` to my requirements.txt file was great when dealing with multiple different OS.

Answer (score 7):

I'd discourage use of `pyreadline` where possible, as it was written to support IPython, and stopped active development when IPython stopped using `readline`/`pyreadline` to support their REPL.

As an alternative, I'd suggest IPython itself; it implements their own tab-completion features (using `prompt_toolkit` as of 5.0) that work in a terminal agnostic fashion. If you install and use `ipython`, you'll get tab completion and the host of other features it provides to improve the interactive experience. Using the `py.exe` manager application bundled with modern Python, install it for Python 3 (in an admin elevated command prompt if Python installed for all users) with:

```
py -3 -mpip install ipython
```

then to run it:

```
py -3 -mIPython
```

If you don't want the whole of `ipython` just to get these features, the `prompt_toolkit` folks do provide [a minimalist `ptpython` REPL](https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/ptpython/) that is basically "Python with a REPL provided by `prompt_toolkit`" without all the other IPython bells and whistles.

Comment: `pyreadline` still seems to work for Python 3.9. Is your objection to it pragmatic or ideological?

Comment: @CraigMcQueen: `pyreadline` is attempting to emulate `readline` and it does the job just barely well enough to make IPython "not the worst". It's been ages since I used it on Windows, but I remember finding it incredibly frustrating when little things didn't work quite the way they did on a native `readline` system (basically always for the worse). The switch to `prompt_toolkit` was a major improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Installing following packages should fix this on both python CLI and `pyspark` shell.

```sh
pip install pyreadline
pip install ipython
```

Comment: I used `pyreadline3` instead of `pyreadline`, as the latter is deprecated.  I have installed python for WIndows 10 64 bit, run it from powershell, and this fixed <TAB> to auto-complete.

Answer (score -4):

For Windows consider to use free Visual Studio Community as Python IDE - it has all autocomplete features out of the box for Python shell (Python Interactive Window) you will likely need: for modules, methods, etc.

In below example I've imported my `DiveIntoPython.py`, once I did it, the name of the module is now into autocomplete suggestions.

[image: Python Interactive Window]

---

If you want to add your own modules paths automatically you should utilize built-in `site` module as described by odjo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59411635/2170898 -> just create `sitecustomize.py` file inside `site.USER_SITE` dir with this content (don't forget to change actual path):

```
import site
site.addsitedir(r'C:\My_Projects')
```